# Errors in ROT13 code (C)

Tags: c, rot13

My program should take in a char, and encode it using ROT13 if it is a letter, and otherwise leave it the same, and then print the result.

My code below works for all lowercase letters, and uppercase letters A-M, but fails on uppercase letters N-Z, and other symbols/numbers. Any help appreciated :)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

#define UPPER_START 65
#define UPPER_END 90
#define LOWER_START 97
#define LOWER_END 122

#define UPPER_MID 77
#define LOWER_MID 109


void testEncode (void); int isValid (char cipherChar); char encode (char letter);

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

    char cipherChar;

    scanf("%c", &cipherChar);
    if (isValid(cipherChar) == TRUE) {
        printf("%c", encode (cipherChar));
    } else if (isValid(cipherChar) == FALSE) {
       printf("%c", cipherChar);
    }
       return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}

int isValid (char cipherChar) {

    int valid;

    if ((cipherChar >= UPPER_START) &&
        (cipherChar <= UPPER_END)) {
        valid = TRUE;
    } else if ((cipherChar >= LOWER_START) &&
            (cipherChar <= LOWER_END)) {
        valid = TRUE;
    } else {
        valid = FALSE;
    }

    return valid;
}

char encode (char letter) {

    if ((letter <= UPPER_MID) || (letter <= LOWER_MID)) {
        letter = letter + 13;
    } else {
        letter = (letter - 13);
    }

    return letter;
}
```

Comment: In your encode function, I would just use the mod operator (`%`). A lot easier.

Comment: If you have access to a C99 compiler (there are a few), you can include `#include <stdbool.h>` and instead of using an `int`, you can use a `bool`, and instead of `TRUE` and `FALSE` you can use the standard `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 2):

[ROT13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) generally doesn't affect characters other than `[A-Za-z]`, so I'd say just ignore those. unless you have some reason to rotate them as well. For example, sometimes 0-9 are treated with ROT5.

In any case, your `if` statement with the clause `(letter <= UPPER_MID) || (letter <= LOWER_MID)` basically says, "any character before 'a' gets 13 added to it", so that's why [N-Z] aren't working correctly. Instead, try breaking out the upper- and lower-case logic and handling the wrap-around per-case, like this:

```
if (letter >= UPPER_START && letter <= UPPER_END) {
    letter = letter + 13;

    if (letter > UPPER_END) {
        letter -= 13;
    }
} else if (letter >= LOWER_START && letter <= LOWER_END) {
    letter = (letter + 13);

    if (letter > LOWER_END) {
        letter -= 13;
    }
}
```